# Information returned by SoundCloud group recorder widget

Tags: soundcloud

I saw the SoundCloud group recording widget here (http://grouprecorder.soundcloudlabs.com) which looks great. I'm wondering if the widget returns the ID of a track once the user finishes uploading it. I'm asking because I want to put the widget in a larger form with fields for pictures, text, etc. and then associate the user's uploaded Soundcloud track with the other fields which are stored in my site's database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget itself won't provide access to the id. But you could use it's source code as a base to build a custom version for yourself:

https://github.com/soundcloudlabs/soundcloud-group-recorder

The SC.recordUpload callback will have the full track object including it's id.